# How to download html file from server (not local) in NSString

Tags: html, objective-c, nsstring

I have a html file on some server. The html file only contains text no photo's or anything else.

What I want to do is download the html file and put the text into a `NSString`.
Is this possible?

I found some code a few minutes ago:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/file.html"];
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url
                                            encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                               error: nil];
```

But did not work

Comment: What about using the "error" parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url
                                                       cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval: 20];

NSError *requestError;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
// Send request synchronously.
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                                      returningResponse: &response
                                                                  error: &requestError];

// Get the json string reponse.
NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc]initWithData: responseData
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Tried it but still nothing. many thanks for helping me. what I can see is that there is data in responsedata, but stringresponse remains empty